# How to configure eclipse to autosave on run?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, intellij-idea, autosave

I'm looking for a configuration or plugin for eclipse that automatically saves files (so I don't have to use Ctrl+S). It could do it on lost focus or over some period of time. I think I saw something like that (I know IDEA has it), but I cant find it now.

Comment: No need to install more plugin. Please take a look on my answer below

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Update seven years later (Eclipse Neon 4.6)

[Eclipse now has an Automatic Save of dirty editors](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/platform.php#autosave-dirty-editors)

> The autosave option is disabled by default.
>   A new autosave preference page (`Preferences > General > Editors > Autosave`) is available and allows to enable/disable the autosave and change the interval of autosave.
>   The countdown is reset on keyboard activity, mouse click, or when a popup is displayed (e.g. content assist, preference page, ...).

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/images/autosave-preference-page.png]

---

Original answer (2009)

The [OP IAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30453/iadapter) added [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142547/how-to-configure-eclipse-to-autosave-on-run/1142568?noredirect=1#comment960457_1142568):

> I bet plugin like I describe exists.

... and you are right!

Eclipse plugin [**saveDirtyEditor**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/savedirtyeditor/) should do just what you need.
Copy the `SaveDirtyEditors_1.0.2.jar` in your plugin directory.

You will get a new preference page under

```
General > Editors > Text Editors > Save Dirty Editors
```

, allowing you to save dirty files like '`myfile.java`' under '`myfile.java.snapshot`' every 30 seconds (can be less if you want).

---

Without additional plugin, though, Eclipse does not support natively that feature.

The closest could be:

```
Window > Preferences > type "build"
  > General > Workspace > [x] Save automatically before build
```

That way, each time you hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for actually building your sources, they would be saved.
But I realize this is not *exactly* what you are after.
Beware your option would not be very efficient with the "build automatically" option activated... (that would trigger too much builds)

Again, without achieving exactly what you are looking for, you also have:

```
Run/Debug > Launching > Save required dirty editors before launching
Run/Debug > Launching > [x] Build (if required) before launching
```

---

Note: the difference between IntelliJ IDEA and eclipse is the "compile on save" feature:

As mentioned in the [IDEA FAQ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_from_netbeans_faq.html#Can_I_enable_compile_on_save_in_IntelliJ_IDEA):

> Q:
>   Can I enable "compile on save" in IntelliJ IDEA?
>
> IntelliJ IDEA currently doesn't support this feature.
>   However there is an "[Eclipse-mode](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=3822)" plug-in which provides similar functionality, so we suggest you to try this plug-in.
>   **Note that by default IntelliJ IDEA saves the files for you, so you don't have to press the Ctrl+S shortcut frequently like you need to do in other IDEs.**

However, with Eclipse, the "build on save" is activated by default, hence the absence of that particular feature.

Comment: I build from console since Maven plugin has sometimes problem with open projects. I bet plugin like I describe exists.

Comment: The plugin doesn't work as expected. It saves a copy of the file, rather than just saving the file :(

Comment: @Karl: strange, I did test it (on a eclipse4.5Mx at the time) and it was working as advertised... What is your configuration? (version of eclipse and of JDK)

Comment: @VonC what is `01` in `01 added` , the very first statement of your answer?

Comment: @mtk it was the name of the OP at the time he/she [wrote the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142547/how-to-configure-eclipse-to-autosave-on-run/1142568?noredirect=1#comment960457_1142568) (5+ years ago). I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 16):

http://code.google.com/p/eclatosa/

"Saves all open editors in eclipse when deactivating the eclipse window (like in IntelliJ)"

Comment: +1 - this plugin actually has an update site unlike saveDirtyEditor

Answer (score 2):

No need to install more plugin.

**Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace**
and there you can check:

```
Save automatically before build + Build automatically
```

If that doesn't work try this:

**Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Save dirty editors before launching**

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin a long time ago to do this that still seems to work: http://www.stateofflow.com/projects/71/save-me

It saves the editor when it loses focus. However, if you switch away from eclipse it doesn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Goto Eclipse **Preferences > General > Editors > Autosave**

if it not work then try this

**Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Save dirty editors before launching**