# Eclipse save automatically

Tags: eclipse, ide, autosave

I would like Eclipse to automatically save every time I edit a file, in much the same way that it builds automatically. Because I've been using IntelliJ for the last year (which saves automatically by default), I keep having the following problem:

- Make some changes in Eclipse
- Forget to press save
- Run the build, unit tests, and notice some strange behaviour
- (Some time later....) realize that the unexpected behaviour occurred because I forgot to save the changes

Is there any way I can make Eclipse save automatically?

Comment: I would recommend against using auto-save plugins. The reason is that a save will always cause an incremental build.  If you are using Java only, this is not  problem.  But, when you start using other languages, like AspectJ, Groovy, or even non-compiled languages like JavaScript, incremental builds can be much longer. This is because a change in a single file can cause a much longer build (since dependency graphs between files tend to be denser).  I would recommend using the "Save automatically" option instead of the autosave plugins.

Comment: No need to install more plugin. please look at my answer below

Answer (score 118, accepted):

#### Eclipse Neon (4.6)

**Window** > **Preferences**

[image: Window Preferences]

**General** > **Editors** > **Autosave** > check **Enable autosave for dirty editors** > choose the value for autosave interval (in seconds)

[image: General Editors Autosave]

Details in [M7](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/M7/):

> Auto-save of dirty editors is now available in Eclipse. The autosave option is **disabled by default**. A new autosave preference page (**Preferences > General > Editors > Autosave**) is available and allows to enable/disable the autosave and change the interval of autosave. The countdown is reset on keyboard activity, mouse click, or when a popup is displayed (e.g. content assist, preference page, ...).

Answer (score 34):

You can go here and check the box Save automatically before build

Windows > Preferences > General -> Workspace

Answer (score 20):

First, try Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace. There you can check "Save automatically before build" and "Build automatically."

**If that does not work**,

**PLEASE TRY**

> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> **"Save dirty editors before
>   launching"**

Comment: Only the second one worked for my JUnit tests, thanks.

Answer (score 19):

You can do it with the **[saveDirtyEditor plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/savedirtyeditor/)** as referenced in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142547/eclipse-autosave-plugin). There is no non-plugin way of doing it.

Comment: There is a non-plugin way of doing it, given by umitems answer.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn Thats for more recent Eclipse versions. Mars does have the AutoSave option inbuilt.

Answer (score 18):

I wrote an Eclipse plugin for this called [smartsave](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/smart-save#.UUibneZDv5I). It's available in the Eclipse Market Place.

It saves your files at a specified interval and you can even tune it to prevent saving if errors, or warnings, are present in the preferences dialog.

Comment: Hey, nice plugin. It would really be cool if you could filter which tiles (by extension) are saved automatically. For instance, I want to save .txt files, but not .xml files.

Comment: It doesn't work on Eclipse 4.5.1, It doesn't show up in Preferences. Please fix.

Comment: FYI: if formatter is configured to run when a file is saved, it does trigger the formatter when it saves. yay.

Comment: A very nice feature (which I use in MATLAB) is to save file when the file looses focus, mostly on tab switch. This proved to be very effective as it seems that we mostly need files to be saved when we switch to other file.

Answer (score 7):

In Helios this can be done by going to preferences and setting:

> Run/Debug > Launching > Save required dirty editors before launching

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse Mars 2, the settings are below Window > Preferences > General > Workspace. These settings are in minutes and not in seconds.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could go to `Windows > Preferences > Autosave` and set the auto intervals to 1.