# Automatically save files in eclipse when closing tab

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse (CDT) when I close a modified file's tab in the code editor, I'm prompted with whether or not I want to save the file. Unlike when I run the project, I'm not given an option to autosave the file when closing a tab in the prompt that comes up. I haven't been able to find one yet, but is there any setting in the Eclipse Preferences that disable these prompts and automatically save modified files when I close their tabs (not every x time)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto save feature in eclipse neon. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37333915/1391924) also look at other answers to this question [Eclipse save automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2635951/1391924)

Comment: I notice that when Eclipse autosaves due to that setting being enabled, it removes all tabs with nothing in front of them. This can be especially annoying when I skip down to a new line to write something, pause in thought, and then eclipse autosaves, causing my cursor to move to the very first column. Is there any way to disable this?