# Save changes resources before running maven install through m2eclipse

Tags: maven, m2eclipse

I am using m2eclipse and was wondering if there is a way to make it save all the sources when running maven install. I need to do it manually each time and sometimes forget to...

Thanks

Comment: Does Eclipse not warn you to save resources when you try to execute? And this is not right -- the auto save thing. What if you have `ctrl+x`ed something and ran. And then get run time exception and wonder what's wrong?

Comment: There is a setting in Eclipse Editor Preferences or so to save files all the time... not sure where exactly thouhg .. not using Eclipse anymore.

Comment: See [eclipse autosave plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142547/eclipse-autosave-plugin)

Comment: Eclipse auto save settings don't work with the maven plugin unfortunately

Comment: In my case I receive the warning before deploying a WAR to a Tomcat Server, but the build process finished without alerting :(